# Consulta Imagen de fondo Android

Tags: android

queria saber como puedo configurar una imagen de fondo, para que se vea en absolutamente toda la pantalla, saque el ActionBar y quiero poner la barra de notificaciones transparente para que la imagen se vea ahi tambien. Gracias de antemano.

Había tratado:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varias opciones, la primera sería definiendo como fondo una imagen mediante la propiedad  `android:background`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/mi_fondo">
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda, mediante un `ImageView` con propiedades,  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` y `android:layout_height="match_parent"` , definiendo una imagen con la propiedad `android:background` :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mi_fondo"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tercera mediante un ImageView,  usando la propiedad `android:scaleType="fitXY"`:

```
   <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Load_img_splash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"                            
            android:src="@drawable/mi_imagen" />
```

y la cuarta, definiendo un tema, donde defines la imagen :

```
<style name="miFondo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/mi_fondo</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

y lo cargas desde tu actividad, definiendo el tema en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/miFondo"></activity>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo hice pero la imagen solo se me pone en el contenido del imageview, y no me queda como un background. la idea es que sea un background que abarque absolutamente toda la pantalla

Comment: Si tu imageView tiene android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" puede abarcar toda la pantalla :P

Comment: Revisa las opciones.

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Para la imagen de fondo, dale un background al Layout con `android:background="@drawable/background_game_screen"`, ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background_game_screen"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la transparencia de la barra de notificaciones prueba colocando esto en tu theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Y si quieres quitar el ActionBar hazlo con esto:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

o por medio del código:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //o en su caso getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```